# Creating a pseudo-random list with r

Tags: r

Given I have 4 different values

```
intensities <- c(0.1,-0.1,0.05,-0.05)
```

My goal is to randomly sample every value 5 times but positive and negative values should alternate, e.g.

resultingList = (0.1, -0.05, 0.05, -0.05, 0.1, -0.1, ...)

Does anybody know an elegant way to do this in R?

Comment: What do you mean by "random sample every value 5 times"?  If you randomly sample from the 4 values there is no guarantee that the +/- minus values will be equally distributed.  So completely alternating the sequence may be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

```
# seed
set.seed(123)

plus <- rep(intensities[intensities >= 0], each = 5)
minus <- rep(intensities[intensities < 0], each = 5)
out <- numeric(length(plus) + length(minus))
out[seq(1, length(out), 2)] <- sample(plus)
out[seq(2, length(out), 2)] <- sample(minus)
out
# [1]  0.10 -0.05  0.05 -0.10  0.10 -0.05  0.05 -0.05  0.05 -0.10  0.10 -0.05  0.05 -0.05  0.05 -0.10
# [17]  0.10 -0.10  0.10 -0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my solution, which creates a custom function and the argument `n` means the length of output. In addition, `ceiling()` and `floor()` can decide the lengths of odd and even positions.

```
mySample <- function(x, n){
  res <- c()
  res[seq(1, n, 2)] <- sample(x[x >= 0], ceiling(n / 2), T)
  res[seq(2, n, 2)] <- sample(x[x < 0], floor(n / 2), T)
  return(res)
}

intensities <- c(0.1, -0.1, 0.05, -0.05)
mySample(intensities, 10)
# [1]  0.10 -0.10  0.05 -0.05  0.10 -0.05  0.05 -0.05  0.05 -0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list of intensities that you are sampling from come in +/- pairs, you could just sample from the list of positive values then change the sign of every other number drawn:

```
N <- 5
positiveIntensities <- c(0.1, 0.05)
resultingList <- sample(positiveIntensities,N,replace = T) * (-1)^(0:(N-1))
```

Comment: I thought of this as well. The problem with this is, that we don't get the same number of negative 0.05 and 0.1 values

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood that constraint.